# Can not upload doc or docx file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter framework.I want to upload doc or docx file.So i have write code like this:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/resume/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'docx|doc|DOC|DOCX';

$this->upload->initialize($config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('resume'))
{
    print_r($error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()));
}
else
{
    $upload = $this->upload->data();
    print_r($upload);exit;
}
```

Here, it shows and error like **The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.** And file is not uploaded.

I have also modify **mimes.php** file and add

```
'doc'    =>    array('application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-office'),
'docx'    =>    array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip', 'application/msword', 'application/x-zip'),
```

When I print **$this->upload->data()** then it shows file_type as **application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text**

But, its not working.So how can I upload doc or docx file?

Comment: what is your CI version?

Comment: @Abdulla its 2.2.6

Comment: did you load library??

Comment: @Abdulla yes i have load library.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have created doc array in mimes.php like this :

```
'doc'    =>    array('application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-office','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text')
```

and its working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text" in your array of allowed mime types.

Comment: Should I have to write **application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text** in doc array?

Comment: Yes you should. If the file you are uploading is a .doc add it to the "doc" array. If it is .docx add it to that array.

You may find a lot more mime types, it depends on the application creating the file. So always log that value when the upload fails so you can add them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> **Don't forget `max_size` and allowed type to `txt`**

```
$config['allowed_types']        = 'txt|doc|docx';
$config['max_size']             = 10000;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

---

If still fails **load OpenOffice extension** too

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet | application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text | application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation | 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document | application/vnd.ms-excel | application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation | txt';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the mimes.php file

```
'binary/octet-stream'
```

for each office document type you want to support. Not an ideal solution but works for me.